# Android EditText look

Tags: android, android-edittext

I wanna make the  editText to look like this:
[image: desired]

what else should I do after I set the editText's background how can I make the text start inside the edittext via code.

Comment: If you use a 9 patch image for background, you can just set it to start expanding only from that point to the end.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to android how can I do so?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to get the EditText to say "Username" by default, but not have that be the actual text?

For that you can use [EditText.setHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) (inherited from TextView) or in the xml definition use android:hint, such as

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Username" />
```

Comment: No I'm trying to make the text start where the Username word started :). But, I want to do this also so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

To make text look like that, set the Gravity attribute to left. The gravity of EditText element.

Answer (score 0):

As well as setting the background of the EditText view, set left and right padding, e.g.

```
<EditText 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp" />
```